# remove space in bootstrap template

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span9"></div>
  <div class="span3"></div>
</div>

+-----------------------+---------------+---+
| span9 contents here   | span3 content | ->|-----space appearing here
+-----------------------+---------------+---+
```

How can I remove spacing of right side. I can't see padding and or margin value applied in but also space is appearing?

---

**Update:**

I found the reason why it was showing the space! I have added the following css

```
body, [class*="span"] {margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;}
```

So, without removing this css can I remove the space?

Comment: You've to show related css class too! fiddle will be a better option

Comment: using bootstrap and showing the space why I don't know.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar You need to show the `CSS` you have behind it.

Comment: it's only bootstrap. I haven't yet applied css. but seems bootstrap width is calculating mistakenly.....

Comment: @NavinRauniyar [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/114309). Well that's that....

Comment: @NavinRauniyar Works fine for me here http://www.bootply.com/114313

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your target `div` a class:

```
<div class="row-fluid target">
    <div class="span9">Test1</div>
    <div class="span3">Test2</div>
</div>
```

then you can add these css rules:

```
.target [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 20px !important;     
}

.target [class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0 !important;    
}
```

**[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/114323)**

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4"> 
       <div class="span3"> </div>  
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8 col-md-8">
      <div class="span9"></div>
 </div>
```