# Can I use both version of bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Here in my question [remove space in bootstrap template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824348/remove-space-in-bootstrap-template) the answer (unaccepted one) is in both condition i.e. `span*` it's older version of bootstrap and `col-*` it's newer version of bootstrap.

So, my question is that can I use both version of bootstrap styling? Should I include both version of bootstrap to get work?

---

Or if I include there might be conflict?

---

Or, Can I integrate both css files in one?

Comment: I have not tried it but it will likely conflict. It would probably cause a lot of trouble for you. Thinking about it the both make use of the same classes like 'table' and 'btn' so they would not play well with each other.

Comment: Similar discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496465/bootstrap-2-bootstrap-3-on-same-site

Comment: I do not answer to your question, but you may want to try [Bootply](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/) which is an automatic migration tool for HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you may add a custom CSS file that re-wrap all old CSS names to the new definitions.

Looking at [changes](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/) seems to not raise any conflict (I may be wrong because I didn't try).

On the contrary, having both CSS files (Bootstrap2 and Bootstrap3) will obviously raise problems depending on the order you load the CSS files (remember that CSS are "casscading" definition, only the last one is taken into account).

But, indeed, an upgrade of your HTML code would be the simplest way to go. Using automatic tools such as [Bootply](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/), will make it smoother.

Comment: You mean that you have customized the Bootstrap CSS in a way that do not allow to simply change the underlying CSS files ??? It is scary... :-) Usually, you are supposed to rely on the "cascading" feature to avoid rewriting too much when changing the roots.